minimum changes needed in array to make contiguous elements sum same
This question is asked during an online interview:
There is a service with n servers and the i'th server has a processing power of server[i] units.
A user can assign k different tasks to any contiguous segment of servers from index i to (i+k-1) for any valid index i.
To ensure consistent behavior, we want the sums of processing powers of any of these subarrays to be equal.
To achieve this, we can replace any server with a new server of any processing power.
Given the array server and an integer, k, find the minimum number of servers that must be replaced such that every contiguous subarray of k servers has an equal sum of processing powers.

Example
Suppose n = 4, server = [1, 2, 3, 2], and k = 2.

contiguous sum are [(1,2), (2,3), (3,2)] = [3,5,5]
It is optimal to replace only the first server, => [3,2,3,2] , the contiguous sum are now [(3,2), (2,3), (3,2)] = [5,5,5]
so the answer is 1.
2. Example suppose n = 5, server = [1,2,1,1,2], k = 3
contiguous sum = [(1,2,1), (2,1,1), (1,1,2)] = [4,4,4], so answer is 0
The is the code :
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(2, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,2))); // correct is 1
        System.out.println(solve(2, Arrays.asList(1,2,3))); // correct is 2
                System.out.println(solve(3, Arrays.asList(1,2,1,1,2))); // correct is 0
    }
      private static int solve(int k, List<Integer> server) {
       // here is my code, which fails for 2nd test case.
       long sum = 0;
       for(int i=0; i<k; i++) sum += server.get(i); // get sum of k items
       long current = sum; // assign that to current
       int result = 0;
       int n = server.size();
       for(int i=1; i<=n-k; i++) {
         current += server.get(i+k-1) - server.get(i-1); // get group sum that starts with i
         if(current != sum) result++; // found difference
         if(current > sum) sum = current; // update sum if it is less than current
       }
       return result; 
     }

In my code, I have made an assumption that for a group starting with i, the replacement will be done at server[i] only, but this assumption is not correct for this task. What is the correct approach to solve this problem.

The sum of the subarray server[i+1...i+k] is equal to sum(server[i...i+k-1]) - server[i] + server[i + k] (remove the first element and append the next element).
Since all subarrays of size k must have equal sum, this directly implies that server[i] = server[i + k]. Applying this same logic further, we can find that server[i] must equal server[i + x*k] for all integer x (where i + x*k is a valid index). In other words, the values at all indexes that are in the same equivalence class modulo k must be all equal.
Then, to solve this problem, we can simply replace all elements in the same equivalence class with the most common element in that equivalence class (note that there are k distinct equivalence classes modulo k). This is O(N) as each element is handled exactly once.
static int solve(int k, List<Integer> server) {
    int minChanges = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        var count = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < server.size(); j += k, ++total)
            count.merge(server.get(j), 1, Integer::sum);
        minChanges += total - Collections.max(count.values());
    }
    return minChanges;
}


Thank you, in a group of k values why we need to have server[i] = server[i + k]?

@Sid When we move from one subarray to the next one, we remove the first element and add the next element (as shown in the first part of my answer). So we have sum(server[i...i+k-1]) + server[i+k] - server[i] = sum(server[i+1...i+k]). sum(server[i+1...i+k]) must equal sum(server[i...i+k-1]), so server[i+k] - server[i] = 0 (by subtracting out sum(server[i...i+k-1]) from the equation).
